# How can I boot ubuntu from external Hard disk drive which is connected to Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, boot, raspberry-pi

I have Raspberry Pi 2 which runs on Raspbian OS and External HDD is connected and mounted to it. It is connected to local server. I have a laptop and I want to boot Ubuntu from External HDD which is connected to Raspberry Pi. Is this possible. If yes, then provide me resources and links.

Comment: Why do you like to do this? Is it just an academic interest, or you have a laptop with windows installed and you like to boot it into ubuntu time to time? If the latter, then the way much simpler solution is to create a bootable USB stick with Ubuntu on it.

Comment: Academic interest, I know that I can easily boot Ubuntu from my external hard disk drive by connecting it to my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

If your laptop (I assume that's what you want to boot ubuntu on, but your question is actually not clear on that) supports PXE booting, you can set up PXE, DHCP and TFTP on either the server or the Pi and NFS on the Pi. But it's a lot of work.

[PXEInstallServer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallServer) looks like it might a good starting point.

Comment: I was not looking on exact solution but I needed starting point so that I can get started. Thank you